How to reset zoom (scale) in chromium desktop via javascript?
I have a webpage on a desktop kiosk (ubuntu 20.04) (chromium [url] --kiosk) where I want to let the user zoom in for accessibility purposes, but reset the zoom to the default scale after an inactivity timeout.
This is the meta tag.
    <meta
      name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

I have tried this solution, it reloads the page but it does not seem to reset the zoom.
var inactivityTimeout = 10;

function onInactivity() {
    if (window.visualViewport.scale != 1) {
      window.location.href = '/'
    }
    else {
      resetInactivityTimeout();
    }
  }


function resetInactivityTimeout(event) {
  console.log("Resetting inactivity timeout to " + inactivity_timeout + " seconds");
  let scale = window.visualViewport.scale;
  if (inactivityTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(inactivityTimeout);
  }

  inactivityTimeout = setTimeout(onInactivity, inactivity_timeout * 1000 );
}

resetInactivityTimeout();

document.addEventListener("touchstart", resetInactivityTimeout);

Do you have any advice?
